# Implement Reusable & Configurable ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

In my iOS app I need a common modal `ViewController` (lets call it `GetData`) across multiple parent `ViewControllers`. `GetData` needs to be configurable (as in hide/show some `Views`). `GetData` should be able to return data to the calling `ViewController`.

Here is a simplification of how I'm trying to implement it, based on my reading on SO and other sources on the web:

```
// ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, GetDataDelegate {

    // This shows the data received from GetData
    @IBOutlet weak var textviewResult: UITextView!

    // Call GetData with only mandatory and without optional views
    @IBAction func onClickGetData(_ sender: Any) {
        let getData = GetData(caller: self)
        getData.display(delegate: self)
    }

    // Call GetData with both mandatory and optional data views
    @IBAction func onClickGetDataWithOptional(_ sender: Any) {
        let getData = GetData(caller: self, hasOptional: true)
        getData.display(delegate: self)
    }

    // Delegate function to received data sent by GetData
    func gotData(data1: String, data2: String!) {
        textviewResult.text = "Mandatory: \(data1)"
                + (data2 != nil ? "\nOptional: \(data2!)" : "")
    }
}
```

---

```
// GetData.swift

import UIKit

protocol GetDataDelegate {
    func gotData(data1: String, data2: String!)
}

class GetData: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldMandatory: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldOptional: UITextField!
    // View with the optional views
    @IBOutlet weak var stackViewOptional: UIStackView!

    var delegate:GetDataDelegate?
    var caller:UIViewController?
    var hasOptional:Bool?

    init(caller: UIViewController, hasOptional: Bool? = false) {
        super.init(nibName: "GetData", bundle: nil)

        self.caller = caller
        self.hasOptional = hasOptional
    }

    func display(delegate:GetDataDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate

        let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "GetData", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GetData")
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve

        caller?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @IBAction func onSubmit(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        delegate?.gotData(data1: textfieldMandatory.text!, data2: hasOptional! ? textfieldOptional.text! : nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Configure GetData (hide/show views)
        // But hasOptional is nil!
        //stackViewOptional?.isHidden = !hasOptional!
    }
}
```

---

I am facing the following issues:

1. The `delegate` `func` is not being called in `GetData`.
2. I'm not able to make changes to `GetData` `views` (in `func` `viewWillAppear`).

Both of the above seem to be because the `members` `delegate` (in `func` `onSubmit`) and `hasOptional` (in `func` `viewWillAppear`) being `nil` even after initialization.

What corrections need to be made or do I need to adopt a different approach?

**Note**: The above is a simplification. In my actual use case there are multiple view controllers which will call `GetData` with or without the optional `Views`.

Comment: What is the purpose of creating an instance (`init(caller:`) of a class `GetData` which later creates another instance (`instantiateViewController`) of the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working as per my requirements:

```
// ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, GetDataDelegate {

    // This shows the data received from GetData
    @IBOutlet weak var textviewResult: UITextView!

    // Call GetData with only mandatory and without optional views
    @IBAction func onClickGetData(_ sender: Any) {
        GetData.generate(caller: self)
    }

    // Call GetData with both mandatory and optional data views
    @IBAction func onClickGetDataWithOptional(_ sender: Any) {
        GetData.generate(caller: self, hasOptional: true)
    }

    // Delegate function to received data sent by GetData
    func gotData(data1: String, data2: String!) {
        textviewResult.text = "Mandatory: \(data1)"
                + (data2 != nil ? "\nOptional: \(data2!)" : "")
    }
}
```

---

```
// GetData.swift

import UIKit

protocol GetDataDelegate {
    func gotData(data1: String, data2: String!)
}

class GetData: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldMandatory: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldOptional: UITextField!
    // View with the optional views
    @IBOutlet weak var stackViewOptional: UIStackView!  

    var delegate:GetDataDelegate?
    var hasOptional:Bool?

    static func generate(caller: UIViewController, hasOptional: Bool? = false) {
        let getData = UIStoryboard(name: "GetData", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GetData") as! GetData
        getData.delegate = caller as? GetDataDelegate
        getData.hasOptional = hasOptional
        caller.present(getData, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func onSubmit(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        delegate?.gotData(data1: textfieldMandatory.text!, data2: hasOptional! ? textfieldOptional.text! : nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Configure GetData (hide/show views)
        stackViewOptional?.isHidden = !hasOptional!
    }
}
```

Hope this is a correct approach...

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would be better implement with containers - you can have multiple view controllers on a single screen. Dave DeLong wrote [great articles](https://davedelong.com/blog/2017/11/06/a-better-mvc-part-1-the-problems/) about this approach.